# Need help refreshing list while developing Windows 8 app using HTML, CSS and AngularJS with Windows Azure backend

Tags: html, angularjs, winjs

I am building a sort of warehouse app, which holds balances of items.

Since WinJS seems like a gigantic pain compared to AngularJS I decided to try and do it with a combination of both.

I can add things to my database just fine, and delete them and show them. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to update the list of items when a new item has been added or removed. Can anyone help with this? Or do you figure I should use something else then AngularJs?

Any help would be nice

Comment: Can you share your code (in a plunker, jsbin, jsfiddle, etc.)?

Comment: Welp, jsfiddle can't handle Angular though: http://jsfiddle.net/UUTTv/

Comment: You have to add it as an external library, but I agree that Plunker can be easier to work with angular.

Answer (score 0):

You are initially populating the list int he `populateList` function, like so:

```
$scope.ingredients = ingFromDb.dataSource._list._keyMap;
```

So you'll have a binding you `$scope.ingredients` for your list. In the `addIngredient` or `saveIngredient` functions, you should also update your `$scope.ingredients` array, not just save the newly added ingredient to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rework your code a little bit so it makes things clearer for you.

Here is a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/bqOdx6ZREFNewohDMB9F?p=preview

**First:** if you need to configure things before the angular application is started, do it in your `app.run`. (Please note that I am not familiar with WinJS).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.run(function() {
  WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

  var winapp = WinJS.Application;
  var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

  winapp.onactivated = function (args) {..};
  winapp.oncheckpoint = function (args) {...};

  var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
    "https://skafferidb.azure-mobile.net/",
    "MFnbMHzNGgysVZIFIcHPLgLLRuJkxl87"
  );
});
```

Or if you can't, do like you did but [bootstrap Angular manually](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) after your things are ready.

**Second:** if you need to access to a database, use factories to wrap your calls to make them reusable accross your application. Here I tried to mimic your Ingredients database queries with a fake factory.

```
app.factory('DbIngredients', function($q, $timeout) {

  var ingredients = [
    {id:1, name:'Banana', sum: 1, unit: 3},
    {id:2, name:'Apple', sum: 2, unit: 1},
    {id:3, name:'Orange', sum: 3, unit: 2},
  ];

  var maxid = 1000;

  return {
    getTable: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(ingredients);
      }, 1000);

      return deferred.promise; 
    },
    insert: function(item) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        item.id = maxid++;
        ingredients.push(item);
        deferred.resolve(ingredients);
      }, 1000);

      return deferred.promise;
    },
    remove: function(item) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function() {
        var chance = Math.random() >= 0.25;
        var index = ingredients.indexOf(item);
        if (chance && index >= 0) {
          ingredients.splice(index, 1);
          deferred.resolve(ingredients);
        } else {
          deferred.reject("Error: Remove!");
        }
      }, 1000);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

I used the `$q` and `$timeout` services to create a deferred promise to simulate a remote call to your database. Here you would replace the `$timeout` part with your own database call and on the reponse of that call, you would send its data to your controller via `deferred.resolve` or `deferred.reject` if an error happened.

**Third:** Use the factories in your controllers. Since we returned deferred promises from our factories calls, we have to wait for the async response. You can do that using `then` which can take two functions: the first is the success callback (deferred.resolve), the second is the error callback (deferred.reject).

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, DbIngredients, DbUser, DbUnits) {
  // ...

  DbIngredients.getTable().then(function(response) {
    $scope.ingredients = response;
  });

  DbUser.getDisplayNameAsync().then(function (response) {
    $scope.username = response;
  })

  DbUnits.getTable().then(function(response) {
    $scope.units = response;
  });

  // ...
});
```

When you receive the response, you can put it in your scope variables to use the values in your view.

**Fourth:** You tried to do form validation before inserting and removing ingredients to the database. Angular has nice form validation features built-in and it makes our life a lot easier to perform validation.

For example, you validated that the ingredients had a name, sum and unit on the click event. In angular, you can use the `ng-required="true|false"` directive on your `input` fields to force a value. The state of every fields in your form is accessible trough `formName.fieldName.$valid|$invalid|$dirty|$pristine`. For more informations, refer to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

```
<form name="formctrl" class="addingredientform">
    <h2>{{username}}s Skafferi</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newingredient.name" ng-required="true" placeholder="Råvara"/>
    <input type="number" ng-model="newingredient.sum" min="0" ng-required="true" placeholder="Antal" id="num"/>
    <select ng-model="newingredient.unit" ng-options="units.indexOf(unit) as unit for unit in units" ng-required="true">
    </select>
    <input type="number" ng-model="newingredient.bestbefore" placeholder="Bäst före (ÅÅÅÅMMDD)" />
    <button ng-click="addIngredient(newingredient)" ng-disabled="formctrl.$invalid">Add</button>
    <span ng-show="formctrl.$dirty && formctrl.$invalid" class="errormessage">Form is invalid!</span>
</form>
```

Here I added the `ng-required` directive on your fields and disabled the Add `button` using the `ng-disabled` directive when the form is `$invalid` (any field that is invalid will make the whole form invalid). Also, I display an error message when the form is invalid and  `$dirty` (has been modified). If you look at the `ng-model` of your fields, I created a `newingredient` object and mapped the fields and send this object in parameter to the àddIngredient` function.

If, and only if, the form is valid, we can enter this function from the `ng-click` of the add button. We receive the `newingredient` object and we call the factory to insert it. Then, we wait for the response that we put back in our scope variable (angular will automatically update the view, since it watches for any changes).

```
$scope.addIngredient = function (newingredient) {
    $scope.sending = "Adding...";
    DbIngredients.insert(newingredient).then(function (response) {
      $scope.ingredients = response;
        $scope.sending += " Success...";
        $timeout(function() { $scope.sending = ""; }, 1000);
    });
    $scope.formctrl.$setPristine();
    $scope.newingredient = {};
}
```

Now, it also depends on what your call to the database will return, if it only returns the inserted object instead of the whole list again, you might have to, either redo the call to getTable or push the object in the existing list (`$scope.ingredients.push(newingredient)`). Finally, we reset the form to its `$pristine` state and we empty the `newingredient` object.

**Fifth:** We do something similar for the removal of the ingredients.

```
<div ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients" class="listingredient">
    {{ingredient.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="ingredient.sum" placeholder="{{ingredient.sum}}" class="num" />
    {{units[ingredient.unit]}} 
    <button ng-click="removeIngredient(ingredient)">Remove</button>
  </div>
```

Here is an example of the success and errors callbacks that you can receive from a promise. To simulate an error, there is 25% chance of failing the call.

```
$scope.removeIngredient = function (ingredient) {
    $scope.sending = "Removing...";
    DbIngredients.remove(ingredient).then(
      // success
      function(response) {
        $scope.ingredients = response;
        $scope.sending += " Success...";
        $timeout(function() { $scope.sending = ""; }, 1000);
      },
      // error
      function(response) {
        $scope.sending += response;
        $timeout(function() { $scope.sending = ""; }, 1000);
      }
    );
}
```

I hope this gave you some help! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Oh my god, I am humbled at the amount of time and thought you've put into this. Maybe it's as easy as anything to you but jesus, that was so nicely explained. Thanks a bunch!